# Read secrets from vault in a scala application

Tags: scala, hashicorp-vault

I'm trying to read secrets from a vault in a scala application using login by AWSIam. While I'm able to authenticate with vault using this code :

```
val vaultConfig = new VaultConfig()
        .nameSpace(vaultConfig.nameSpace)
        .address(vaultConfig.url)
        .sslConfig(new SslConfig().build())
        .build()

val vault = new Vault(vaultConfig, config.version)
    val token = bcVault.auth()
      .loginByAwsIam(
          "default",
          Base64.getEncoder.encodeToString(config.awsStsEndpoint.getBytes("UTF-8")),
          Base64.getEncoder.encodeToString(config.awsRequestBody.getBytes("UTF-8")),
          Base64.getEncoder.encodeToString(createAwsIamSignedHeader(config).getBytes("UTF-8")),
          config.awsAuthPath
      ).getAuthClientToken
```

While trying to read the secret from the path, its returning empty string. I trying to read via this code snippet :

```
val secret = vault
        .logical()
        .withNameSpace("infrastructure/data-ingestion-streaming")
        .read(secretConfig.path)
        .getData
        .asScala
        .toMap
```

The library used: https://github.com/BetterCloud/vault-java-driver
BetterCloud version: 5.0.0

Scala version: 2.12

Any help in this would be really appreciated .

Comment: Try with local setup of vault, and test the functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you would be using BetterCloud package only, you could create a Java class like this:

```java
public class ConfigReader implements java.io.Serializable {
  public Map<String, String> fetchSecrets() throws VaultException {
    final VaultConfig config = new VaultConfig()
         .address("https://my.vault.com:port/")
         .token("my-secret-token")
         .build();
    // the second argument is optional which talks about the version of the engine and the default value is 2
    final Vault vault = new Vault(config, 1);
    return vault.logical().read("path/to/my/secrets").getData();
  }
}
```

The same then can be used in the Scala file like this:

```scala
val configReader = new ConfigReader() with Serializable
val secrets = configReader.fetchSecrets()
```